# zoomtextview library crashes when more activity is added

Tags: java, android, scrollview, zooming, pinchzoom

I'm trying to build an app with scroll and zoom for the textview using noman zoomtextview library. It was working fine when I imported to project. I added one more activity and copied the exact same code from source project activity to this activity. Now the App crashes. The source project java file is named as ZoomTextView.java and activity_main.xml

one.java File:

```
package noman.zoomtextview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class one extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "ZoomTextView";
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private float defaultSize;

private float zoomLimit = 3.0f;


public one(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public one(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public one(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    defaultSize = getTextSize();
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());

}

public void setZoomLimit(float zoomLimit) {
    this.zoomLimit = zoomLimit;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, zoomLimit));
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, defaultSize * mScaleFactor);
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(mScaleFactor));
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

one.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<noman.zoomtextview.ZoomTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/twentyfive" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="noman.zoomtextview">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your new Activity to your Manifest.

This is how you have to

```
<activity android:name=".YourNewActivity"/>
```

And if your Main Activity is your new Activity then replace this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with

```
<activity android:name=".YourNewActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```